# I want to show a image progress slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, slider

I'm getting a list of image urls from api. I am showing image at zero index on loading api. There's a slider widget, on changing it i put the value as image index and show images based on that. But when i load next image theres a white space which keeps showing. I want it to be smooth as if i am watching a timelapse. I have attached the image below on slider change i want to next image. I used precacheimage as well but it is still showing whitespace/loading when i move slider.

```
Future<void> preloadImages(List<String> imageUrls) async {
for (String url in imageUrls) {
  await precacheImage(CachedNetworkImageProvider(url), context);
}
this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final queryParameters = {
    'country': 'us',
    'category': 'business',
    'apiKey': 'your api key',
  };
  //Get API key from https://newsapi.org/

  HashMap<dynamic, dynamic> data = HashMap<dynamic, dynamic>();
  double _currentSliderValue = 0;
  late final Future myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myFuture = apiCall();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: myFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(child: Text("No data available"));
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    CarouselSlider.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex,
                              int pageViewIndex) =>
                          SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageUrl: snapshot.data[_currentSliderValue.toInt()],
                          placeholder: (context, url) =>
                              const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                              const Icon(Icons.error),
                        ),
                      ),
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        autoPlay: false,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        viewportFraction: 0.9,
                        aspectRatio: 2.0,
                        initialPage: _currentSliderValue.toInt(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Slider(
                      value: _currentSliderValue,
                      max: 20,
                      divisions: 5,
                      label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
                      onChanged: (double value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentSliderValue = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }
            }
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
    );
  }

  Future apiCall() async {
    List<String> list = [];
    var url = Uri.https('newsapi.org', 'v2/top-headlines', queryParameters);

    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse =
          convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      var articles = jsonResponse['articles'];

      for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
        var articleData = articles[i];
        var urls = articleData["urlToImage"];
        if (urls != null) {
          list.add(urls);
        }
      }

      return list;
    } else {
      debugPrint('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: My use case is showing image list in one frame. Like on moving slider images will change and it will look like a timelapse. I achieved it but the problem is on slider change image is chaning but only when i stop slider at any position. if i keep dragging i want to change images. Its not happening, only changing when i stop slider somewhere. i added my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                  child: imageBytesList.isNotEmpty
                      ? Image.memory(
                          // Use the preloaded image bytes instead of fetching from the network
                          // imageBytesList.isNotEmpty ?
                          Uint8List.fromList(currentBytes!),
                          gaplessPlayback: true,
                          
                          // : imageBytesList.first,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                              Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                            return ClipRRect(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/error_image.jpeg',
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      : ClipRRect(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/error_image.jpeg',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
                Slider(
                  activeColor: Helper.primary,
                  thumbColor: Colors.white,
                  min: 0,
                  max: data.length.toDouble() - 1,
                  value: _currentSliderValue,
                  onChangeEnd: (value){
                    setState(() {
                      print("onchnagestart" + value.toString());
                    });
                  },
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentSliderValue = value;
                      currentBytes = imageBytesList[value.round()];
                      // currentslider = value.round();
                      print(value.toString());
                    });
                    // setState(() {});
                  },
                ), this is my code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with first time loader you can wrap your code in Listview like this, then you can use slider to change image like time-lapse.

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final queryParameters = {
    'country': 'us',
    'category': 'business',
    'apiKey': 'your api key',
  };
  //Get API key from https://newsapi.org/

  HashMap<dynamic, dynamic> data = HashMap<dynamic, dynamic>();
  double _currentSliderValue = 0;
  late final Future myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myFuture = apiCall();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: myFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(child: Text("No data available"));
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl:
                                snapshot.data[_currentSliderValue.toInt()],
                            placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                const Icon(Icons.error),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    snapshot.data != null
                        ? Slider(
                            value: _currentSliderValue,
                            max: (snapshot.data?.length ?? 0).toDouble() - 1,
                            divisions: 5,
                            label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
                            onChanged: (double value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _currentSliderValue = value;
                              });
                            },
                          )
                        : const SizedBox(),
                  ],
                );
              }
            }
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
    );
  }

  Future apiCall() async {
    List<String> list = [];
    var url = Uri.https('newsapi.org', 'v2/top-headlines', queryParameters);

    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse =
          convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      var articles = jsonResponse['articles'];

      for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
        var articleData = articles[i];
        var urls = articleData["urlToImage"];
        if (urls != null) {
          list.add(urls);
        }
      }

      return list;
    } else {
      debugPrint('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
    }
  }
}
```